# MySql InnoDB & performance: what is the best structure?

Tags: mysql, database, performance, relational-database, database-performance

For a db that I need to built (InnoDB), I have two different structures in mind and I would like to know which one is best in terms of performance.

I want to store thousands of products. Each product can contain a certain degree -might also be 0- of an ingredient (they're chemical products). There are 26 different ingredients, say A-Z. Each ingredient has its own characteristics.

The question is: how can I best store and link ingredients and products (in terms of performance)?

### Option A

Each row in the table Products has 26 additional fields: one for each ingredient. That fields contains the amount (not a ref-key). Each ingredient-column has an index applied for faster searching. The links between products and ingredients only exist on the level of program logic. There are no link tables in the db.

### Option B

There is a table containing the products, and a table containing the ingredients. The table Products has no fields for the ingredients, but instead there is a link table that links Products to Ingredients and defines the amounts. The links between products and ingredients are now defined on the db-level. This table could become very large.

An alternative option B is that I make a link table for each ingredient, thus ending up with 26 link tables. I'm  not sure whether this is faster when searching...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use option A.  It makes it difficult to add or modify ingredients and, depending on some things, greatly increase the size of the products table.

Option B is the way to go.  Adding or removing ingredients would be trivial and have no practical impact on performance.  If you make the primary key of the link table on `(product_id, ingredient_id)`, the size wouldn't be too bad and the performance would be good.  This method is also the most concise and easiest to manage.

Creating a link table for each ingredient would be needlessly complex and less efficient.